# Finding the lowest missing integer in a vector containing positive and negative int's?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing an operation to find the lowest missing element of a vector, V = 1..N + 1. This has to be performed in **O(N)** time complexity.

Solution One:

```
std::vector<int> A {3,4,1,4,6,7};

int main()
{
    int max_el = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end()); //Find max element
    std::vector<int> V(max_el);
    std::iota(V.begin(), V.end(), 1) //Populate V with all int's up to max element

    for(unsigned into i {0}; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
       int index = A[i] - 1;
       if(A[i] == V[index]) //Search V in O(1)
       {
         V[index] = max_el; //Set each to max_el, leaving the missing int 
       }
    }
    return *std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end()); //Find missing int as its the lowest (hasn't been set to max_el)
}

//Output: 2
```

This works completely fine.

However, I'm now trying to get this to work with vector containing negative int's.

Solution Two:

My logic is to take the same approach, however 'weight' the indexes given the size of the vector and the number of negative int's in the vector:

```
std::vector<int> A {-1, -4, -2, 0, 3, 2, 1}
int main()
{
   int max_el = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
   int min_el = *std::min_element(A.begin(), A.end());
   int min_el_abs = abs(min_el); //Convert min element to absolute
   int total = min_el_abs + max_el;

   std::vector<int> V(total + 1);
   std::iota(V.begin(), V.end(), min_el);
   int index;

   //Find amount of negative int's
   int first_pos;
   for(unsigned int i {0}; i < A.size(); i++)
   {
      if(A[i] >= 0) {first_pos = i; break;}
   }

   for(unsigned int i {0}; i < A.size(); i++)
   {
      if(A[i] <= 0) //If negative
      {
          index = (A.size() - first_pos) - abs(A[i]);
       } else 
       {
          index = (A[i] + 1) + first_pos;
       }
       if(A[i] == V[index])
       {
          V[index] = 0;
       }
    } 
    return *std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end());
 } 

 //Output: -3
```

Solution Two fails to compare the values of the two vectors (A and V), as calculating the `index` with the above methods with a **positive** int doesn't work.

1) How can I get my Solution 2 to work with unordered vector's of negative int's?

2) How can I edit my Solution 2 to work with vectors of positive  as well as vectors with negative int's?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What does it do or not do that it shouldn't do or should do?

Comment: Make another vector for negative ints and use `i*(-1)` instead of `i` as index

Comment: Your solution 1 is not even O(N) if you put a large value in the vector (if N is the size of the vector, not the maximum value). If there are constraints on the values, put them in the question. Extending that solution to negative values is as simple as finding the minimum and subtracting it from all values, then adding it back to the final answer.

Comment: Allocating the `V` vector and filling it with `std::iota` are both O(max_el).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try give my own question an answer, after spending sometime thinking about this:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> A {-3, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4};
  auto relative_pos = std::minmax_elment(A.begin(), A.end());
  std::vector<bool> Litmus( *(relative_pos.second) - *(relative_pos.first), false); //Create vector of size max val - min val)

  auto lowest_val = *(relative_pos.first);
  for(auto x : A)
  {
     Litmus[i - lowest_val] = true;
  }
  auto pos = std::find(Litmus.begin(), Litmus.end(), false); //Find the first occurring false value
  std::cout<< (pos - Litmus.begin()) + lower<<std::endl; //Print the val in A relative to false value in Litmus
}
```

This solution works with negative numbers and is linear.

Answer (score 3):

Your first solution seems O(max(N,M)), where I consider N the number of elements in vector A and M the size of vector V (or *max(A<sub>i</sub>)*), but you are looping through both vectors multiple times (with `std::min_element`, `std::max_element`, the `for` loop, the allocation of V and `std::iota` too).

Besides, once corrected a couple of typos (a missing `;` and an `into` instead of `int`), your program returns the value found... from `main()`, which is a bit odd.

Your first algorithm always searches for the lowest missing value in the range [**1**, max value in A], but it can be generalized to find the lowest missing element in the range [*min(A<sub>i</sub>)*,  *max(A<sub>i</sub>)*], even for negative numbers.

My approach is similar to that of [L.Senioins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594932/4944425), but I've used different library functions trying to minimize the number of loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

template <class ForwardIt>
typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type
lowest_missing(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    if ( first == last )
        throw std::string {"The range is empty"};
    // find both min and max element with one function
    auto result = std::minmax_element(first, last);

    // range is always > 0  
    auto range = *result.second - *result.first + 1;
    if ( range < 2 )
        throw std::string {"Min equals max, so there are no missing elements"};
    std::vector<bool> vb(range); // the initial value of all elements is false

    for (auto i = first; i != last; ++i)
        vb[*i - *result.first] = true;

    // search the first false
    auto pos = std::find(vb.cbegin(), vb.cend(), false);
    if ( pos == vb.cend() )  // all the elements are true
        throw std::string {"There are no missing elements"};

    return std::distance(vb.cbegin(), pos) + *result.first;
}

template <class ForwardIt>
void show_the_first_missing_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << lowest_missing(first, last) << '\n';
    }
    catch(const std::string &msg)
    {
        std::cout << msg << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a { 1, 8, 9, 6, 2, 5, 3, 0 };
    show_the_first_missing_element(a.cbegin(), a.cend());

    std::vector<int> b { -1, -4, 8, 1, -3, -2, 10, 0 };
    show_the_first_missing_element(b.cbegin(), b.cend());
    show_the_first_missing_element(b.cbegin() + b.size() / 2, b.cend());

    std::vector<int> c { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    show_the_first_missing_element(c.cbegin(), c.cend());

    std::vector<int> d { 3, 3, 3 };
    show_the_first_missing_element(d.cbegin(), d.cend());

    std::vector<int> e;
    show_the_first_missing_element(e.cbegin(), e.cend());

    return 0;
}
```

The results outputted for my test cases are:

```
4
2
-1
There are no missing elements
Min equals max, so there are no missing elements
The range is empty
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to make a `bool` vector (or `char` vector just to avoid compilation warnings about casting to `bool`) which has the size of all possible elements. All elements are initialized to 0 and later are assigned to 1 which indicates that the element is not missing. All you need to do then is to find an index of the first 0 element which is the lowest missing element.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> A{ -1, 0, 11, 1, 10, -5 };

int main() {
    if (A.size() > 1) {
        int max_el = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
        int min_el = *std::min_element(A.begin(), A.end());
        int range = abs(max_el - min_el) + 1;

        std::vector<int> V(range, 0);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
            V[A[i] - min_el] = 1;

        if (*std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end()) == 0)
            std::cout << std::distance(V.begin(), std::find(V.begin(), V.end(), 0)) + min_el;
        else
            std::cout << "There are no missing elements" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "There are no missing elements" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::max_element(A.begin(),A.end()); 
    try
    {
        sort(A.begin(),A.end());    
        std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::unique(A.begin(),A.end());
        A.resize(std::distance(A.begin(),it));

        for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < A.size(); i++)
        {
            if( A[i] != j)          
            {
                return j;
            }           
            j++;
        }

    }
    catch(exception &e)
    {
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    return ++(*it);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by others will not work or get you a 100% score, us this implementation instead.

```
// you can use includes, for example:
// #include <algorithm>

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    std::vector<bool> visited(1'000'001, false);
    
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, A.begin(), A.end(), [&visited](int& i){
        int mask = i >> 31;
        int idx = i & ~mask;
        visited[idx] = true;
    });

    auto lower_bound = std::find(visited.begin() + 1, visited.end(), false);
    return static_cast<int>(std::distance(visited.begin(), lower_bound));

}
```